# SQL Server 2008. Are these 2 statements equal

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, isnull

```
DECLARE @IS_EMAIL CHAR(1);

IF @IS_EMAIL = '1' .....

IF (ISNULL(@IS_EMAIL , '0') = '1') .....
```

Will those 2 condition resolve to the same result for every value of `@IS_EMAIL`?

Comment: Yes. Both IF's will only execute when the value is '1'. In the second IF the value null is mapped to '0' first. But zero is irrelevant for the IF to pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they will work the same.

Second one will evaluate to `if 0 = 1` when @IS_EMAIL is null.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But consider the first one as it's easier to understand and it should be faster.